# How to run multiple JavaFX tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, javafx, junit

I have to test some `Spring` application with `JavaFx` GUI. Unfortunately, I can't run them together, one by one. I'm using `Java 11`, `JUnit 5.3` and `TestFX` library.

I tried to add methods like:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
        launch(Main.class);
    }
```

and I though it will restart application again and work properly. Unfortunately, just one test starts in a proper way and execute. In other cases I get error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-2)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
```

Whole testing class looks now like that:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
        launch(Main.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.show();
    }
    @Test
    public void testRegisterButton()
    {
        clickOn("#register_button");
    }
    @Test
    public void testLoginButton()
    {
        sleep(200L);
    }
}
```

There are just a simple example tests. Previous I made 
`init()` function without `@Before`, just with launch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to disable JMX  auto-configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    JmxAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Or

```
spring.jmx.enabled = false
```